# What is the sum of recursive logarithms?

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, computational-complexity

I am trying to deduce the complexity of a rather odd algorithm. I have got it down to this form:

$$
O(n \times (\sqrt n)^2 + n \times (\lg \sqrt n)^2 + n \times (\lg \lg \sqrt n)^2 +  \space ... + \space n \times a^2)
$$

$$
= O(n^2 + n \times (\lg n)^2 + n \times (\lg \lg n)^2 +  \space ... + \space n \times a^2)
$$
Where $a$ is a constant value.

I have a hunch that in the limit to infinity $n^2$ dominates. However I do not know how to prove this. Is there a closed form for the sum of recursive logarithms, such as I have in the above formula?

Comment: First of all, $lg\sqrt n)^2$ does not equal $(\lg n)^2$. And what do the $\dots$ indicate? $\lg\dots\lg\sqrt n$ is eventually not a real number when there are enough $\lg$s.

Comment: @SteveKass but $\Theta(\lg^2\sqrt{n}) = \Theta(\lg^2{n})$

Comment: Edited to make it more clear that I am talking about asymptotic analysis. Also the ... indicates that the log function is recursive. Eg $\lg n + \lg \lg n + \lg \lg \lg n + \lg \lg \lg \lg n + ... + a$ and so on until it is at some constant $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. $n^2$ dominates. It is because $\log(n)$ is asymptotically lower than $n$ and $n$ is asymptotically lower than $n^2$. This is very easy to prove. If your book/class allows you to assume this then just state it and you're done. If this assumption is not allowed(well it should be) you can prove by showing that,

$$\frac{d(\log(x))}{dx}\lt\frac{dx}{dx}\lt \frac{d(x^2)}{dx}$$

for sufficiently large $x$.

Comment: Thank you. I am a little confused about this. Why is $\lg n + \lg \lg n ... O(n)$?

Comment: @user135125 if $f'(x)\gt g'(x) \forall x\gt k$, then $g(x)=\Theta(f(x))$

Comment: Aha, thanks. I get it now!